# getting only first 10 updates directy from json page,not downloading the whole page first then select from it

Tags: android, json

i want to download  the top 10 new updates only from json page,,,

this below code  download alldata in  the page first then i select what i want ,,,but i need it to only download latest 10 updates from the server without downloading the whole page first

so to get the code as fast aspossible  because this page is huge,
thanks in advance,

```
public String readFeed() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                "http://www.zigwheels.com/api/zigtvApi.php?method=data&module=News&section=News");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null  ) {

                    builder.append(line);


                }
            } else {
                Log.e(GridViewExampleActivity.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,You will need to make changes in your Web Service, Make your web developer to give you another url which will only consist data for top 10 new updates, and then the above code at Android side.

Comment: i think there is a way to get it from Android

Comment: how you will download half of the response ? - not possible

Comment: whatever library you use..that library will give you top 10 record,,but it background they have downloaded the whole response...so its all same.

Answer (score 0):

You need [google-gson-stream](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/detail?name=google-gson-stream-2.1.jar&can=2&q=) for that . Think of it a SAX XML parser

Comment: do u have a tutorial for that?

Answer (score 0):

Soni is right - there should be a way for the web service to give you only the first 10 updates. The line

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
```

will not return unless the data is received in full, so any chance of speeding up the load process should be done server-side. Probably an additional

`&count=10`

on your request that the server can interpret.